# Create/update JIRA issues from Excel file

Tags: java, api, integration, jira

Is it possible to import excel/csv file (which contains details of jira issue like Title, Description, Type, Priority) in jira using any **open source** Tool or API in Java?

It should log hours and update comments as well.

**EDIT:** I don't want to upload excel file, rather than I want to create/update issues on jira using excel/csv file upload.

Comment: You want to create JIRA tickets based on excel rows? That would be doable using Apache POI and JIRAs REST API. How is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Yes, @AndersR.Bystrup you are right, I am aware about this, but my question : is there such tool/api already exist for me? So I want to confirm, I am not wasting my time..!

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen an open source tool that does exactly that as JIRA has built in importing functionality for CVS/Excel.

The one opensource tool to mention would be the [REST Java Client for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.jira-rest-java-client) to communicate to your specific JIRA instance that could be used in conjunction with Apache POI to perform what you require.